# Functions acting on the right

Tags: functions, notation

My question is with regards to correct notation when a function "acts on the right". In the following $A, S \neq \emptyset$, $A^{*}$ denotes the free monoid on $A$ and Map$(S, S)$ all maps with domain and codomain $S$.

Specifically I have a map $\mu\,\colon S \times A \rightarrow S$ and a map $\phi\,\colon A \rightarrow$ Map$(S, S),\ a \mapsto \mu(\,\cdot\,, a)$.

I extend this to the map $\Phi\,\colon A^{*} \rightarrow$ Map$(S, S),\ a_{1}\dots a_{n} \mapsto \phi(a_{n}) \circ \dots \circ \phi(a_{1})$.

This is (the unique extension to) a monoid antihomomorphism. A friend made a passing comment about using "maps acting on the right" to make a monoid homomorphism and I was wondering whether the following image

[(I had to use unsupported notation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjvZ3.png)

is accepted notation.

Comment: What algebraic object is $S$? $A$? Modules over what? In your image, didn't you just write every arrow from right to left? What's the point?

Comment: Also, how is a function or map acting on anything here? All I see is $A$ acting on $S$.

Comment: Monoid (anti)homomorphism, not modules -- sorry! I have modules on the brain. 

$A$ is an alphabet here, which is just a non-empty set, and $S$ is a set of states for some machine. 

Yes, I did, but I did it so as not to have to introduce monoid antihomomorphisms as when the function maps on the right it is a monoid homomorphism. It will save me a world of pain later in the document I am preparing, and I am also interested in functions acting on the right.

Comment: Standard usage of $\circ$ is too well-established to be redefined (ditto the usage of colons), but you could define the opposite operation (sometimes denoted by a semicolon, as mentioned in Wikipedia's article on function composition), and have a map from $A^*$ into the *opposite* of the monoid $\operatorname{Map}(S, S)$. This solves your problem locally, without requiring a global change to writing function application/composition on the right. Even if you do decide to make such a drastic global change, you don't need to make arrows go from right to left (although it can be done in diagrams).